# Solving an ODE with a random variable with a custom pdf

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following ODE:

[image: ODE]

where `p` is a probability, and `y` is a random variable with pdf:

[image: see link]

`epsilon` is a small cut-off value (typically 0.0001).

I am looking to numerically solve this system in `Python`, for `t = 0` to about `500`.

Is there a way I can implement this using `numpy/scipy`?

Comment: A simple google search will lead you [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

Comment: @MaJoR: [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) does not solve [stochastic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594290/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-integrate-a-system-of-stochastic-differential

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, excuse me for that, but when I commented that bit, OP had not mentioned what type of DEs he wanted to solve. He simply blurted out ODEs. And for a generic question, I left a generic comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an annoying lack of quality Python packages for SDE integration. You have kind of an unusual setup, in that your random variable has an explicit dependence on your integrand (at least it appears that `y` depends on `p`). Because of this, it'll probably be hard to find a preexisting implementation that meets your needs.

Fortunately, the simplest method for SDE integration, [Euler-Maruyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method), is very easy to implement, as in the `eulmar` function below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def eulmar(func, randfunc, x0, tinit, tfinal, dt):
    times = np.arange(tinit, tfinal + dt, dt)
    x = np.zeros(times.size, dtype=float)
    x[0] = x0

    for i,t in enumerate(times[1:]):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + func(x[i], t) + randfunc(x[i], t)

    return times, x
```

You could then use `eulmar` to integrate your SDE like so:

```
def func(x, t):
    return 1 - 2*x

def randfunc(x, t):
    return np.random.rand()

times,x = eulmar(func, randfunc, 0, 0, 500, 5)
plt.plot(times, x)
```

[image]

You'll have to supply your own `randfunc` however. Like above, it should be a function that takes `x` and `t` as arguments and returns a single sample from your random variable `y`. If you're having trouble coming up with a way to generate samples of `y`, since you know the `PDF` you can always use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) (though it does tend to be fairly inefficient).

#### Notes

- This is not a particularly efficient implementation of Euler-Maruyama. For example, the random samples are usually generated all at once (eg `np.random.rand(500)`). However, you can't pre-generate your random samples, since `y` depends on `p`.